# VRMLLoader from three.js error on Angular 6 project

Tags: angular, three.js, vrml

When loading a sample .wrl file using VRMLLoader from three-full npm package into Angular 6 project I get the following error:

> Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined" at VRMLLoader.parse() method.

In my component I have the following code:

```
import { VRMLLoader } from 'three-full';
const loader = new VRMLLoader();
loader.load('../assets/images/sample.wrl', (group) => {}, 
error => console.error(error));
```